# Can patching a version string literal in an ELF binary break the program?

Tags: c, gcc

My application ships with lots of console helper programs. When making a new release, I'd like to update the version number in those console helper programs to reflect the version number of the main program. The helper programs are all written in C and compiled using gcc. The version string is stored in a `const char*` string literal and all the program does with that version string is `printf()` it.

Now I know that hacking binaries certainly is no good practice at all and should be avoided. Still, I'm curious whether from a *technical point of view this would be possible* without causing any harm, i.e. breaking the binary or the binary getting marked as having been tampered with etc. That's of course something I'd like to avoid.

The binaries aren't codesigned or anything. They're plain console programs written in C and compiled using gcc. A test has shown that this indeed seems to work fine but still I'd like to know if it's maybe just luck that it works or if this is guaranteed to work.

Comment: As long as the overall length of the string doesn't grow, you can probably (usually) get away with it, unless the executable format includes a checksum to detect tampering.  I've worked with software that does more hideous things than adjust the version number and it's worked on numerous platforms over many years.  But if you're seeking a guarantee — nope, I can't promise you that it is guaranteed.

Comment: Yeah, of course the string doesn't grow. It's like changing 1.0 into 1.1 and such. Still, if there were checksums that could detect such changes, I'd be in trouble. That's pretty much what I'd like to know in this question...

Comment: Be wary: versions have a tendency to grow: 1.9.2 becomes 1.10.0 in [semantic versioning](https://semver.org/).  Or someone decides to add build information because it's a patch release: `1.9.2` becomes `1.9.3+linux-5.13-amd64`.  Etc.

Comment: Of course, I'm taking care of that. I can guarantee that the string doesn't grow.

Comment: Then, in practice, you will get away with modifying the binaries.  But I don't think there's a guarantee that it will always work.  OTOH, I've not studied the ELF format and it may well be that there's no provision for checksums and hence things "can't" break.  Note that if you modify the software on the machine where it is installed, then you might want to develop checksums for the installed software.  Checksums from the distribution medium won't help if the code is modified as it is installed.  (Think "licence numbers" and "activation keys", and even "paths to shared libraries".)

Comment: Aside from the main question, if you want to avoid recompiling all the helper programs, store the version string in an object module all by itself and link it into each program. Then, when updating, you only have to relink, not recompile. As a side bonus, creating an ELF binary by using the linker is a fully supported way to update a string literal in it.

Comment: C compilers are free to produce executables with multiple references to string constants that are substrings of each other. A reference to "2" might equal "Version 1.9.2"+12.

Comment: If you want to patch, but the string might grow, the simple solution is to just specify a larger than needed string. (e.g.) instead of `char *version = "1.2.3";` do: `char version[20] = "1.2.3";` Then, you could patch to version (e.g.) `12.137.6285` if you wished

Comment: @MarkPlotnick: Yeah, I've seen that in one case where the string apparently got split in two halves. In that case, I had to manually adapt it which was easy because it is a long version string but you are right that it could get tricky if the string is split like in your example. Still, the question remains if it's a safe thing to do, obviously given that everything is taken care of (like that the string doesn't grow or shrink and that it is guaranteed that the bytes that are modified really belong to the version string and not to something else).